# Power query from Microsoft Exchange zip folder attachment

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to get data from my email and the data is attached to an email and compressed in a zip folder.Is there a way to extract the contents of the zip folder from my email and into power query?

This is what I have so far

let Source = Exchange.Contents("xxxxx@xxx.com"), Mail1 = Source{[Name="Mail"]}[Data], #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Mail1, each ([Folder Path] = "\xxxx Report\")), #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", let latest = List.Max(#"Filtered Rows"[DateTimeReceived]) in each [DateTimeReceived] = latest), #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Attachments"}), #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", each UnzipContent([Attachments])) in #"Added Custom"

This gives me an error.

Please assist,
Vava

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, instead of posting code in comments.